# Multiple sharedpreference for Multiple users, is it necessary?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

i stored a list of data in sharedpreference which is only viewable by a particular user, however when i try to login another account i am still able to view the data.

Is it due to local development environment so that even if different user logged in we will still read the same sharedpreference file?  Can i assume once the app go into production, the issue will be gone since the users should be using different machine?

If not, how can i achieve multiple sharedpreference for multiple user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely due to the way that you are storing the data. Shared preferences depend on keys `Strings`. If you are storing different users but using the same keyword for all of them, i.e `user`, then it won't be unique.

Specify a unique key for every user, and easiest thing to do is use their email. When you store that data in your shared preferences, use this unique key for every user. This way you don't have data overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Store json data to shared preference as string .

then you can store unique key for each individual user and value for them .

Here is the example of storing json as string : (Note this Example is for Single object , for Multiple user use Array List  with multiple object on it )

```
SharedPreferences shared_User = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            Map decode_options = jsonDecode(jsonString);
            String user = jsonEncode(User.fromJson(decode_options));
            shared_User.setString('user', user);

SharedPreferences shared_User = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            Map userMap = jsonDecode(shared_User.getString('user'));
            var user = User.fromJson(userMap);

    class User {
      final String name;
      final String age;

      User({this.name, this.age});

      factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
        return new User(
            name: parsedJson['name'] ?? "",
            age: parsedJson['age'] ?? "");
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        return {
          "name": this.name,
          "age": this.age
        };
      }
    }
```